# Audit logging for OpenLDAP changes

Tags: openldap, audit

How can I produce and examine an audit trail of changes made to an OpenLDAP database, such as which user was created when, by whom, when was it edited, what was edited etc?

Answer (score 1):

Install and configure the [`auditlog` overlay](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-auditlog&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&format=html).